# What are the risks of using myQNAPcloud?

Tags: network-attached-storage, qnap

In my organization we have QNAP NAS, which is currently behind NAT, but with port forwarding it's accessible from Internet by our domain. Recently I've learned about myQNAPcloud service. As I understand, by registering device with this service, NAS should be accessible by QNAP domain and I could disable all port forwarding on router. In this configuration one needs to know exact domain to even try to do something malicious. I've read some of QNAP documentation of myQNAPcloud but I can't find any downsides or risks of this solution besides not being able to use own domain. What I'm missing? What should I take into consideration before registering with this service?

Comment: I believe [accidental worldwide factory reset](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/wd-my-book-nas-devices-are-being-remotely-wiped-clean-worldwide/) is pretty high on the list of risks you should consider. Recommend you do not use consumer NAS boxes anyway, they are typically so tremendously badly setup they even very commonly get owned by untargeted ransomware.

Comment: I can't change it right now so I try to setup it a little better than default. Thanks for pointing out factory reset thing.